# fullcalendar.js global timezone issues

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

I have a fullcalendar instance that should have the following features:

- events are inputted in user local timezone (no matter which one)
- events should also be shown in user local timezone
- if a user in timezone UTC+2 enters an event on 20:00 pm it should be 22:00 pm for a user in timezone UTC+4 and so on...

what i've done is, i've set the now-attribute:

```
<?php echo json_encode($datetime_string) ?>
```

and i've set the timezone-attribute to "local"

```
timezone:'local',
```

and the "ignoreTimezone to "false"

```
ignoreTimezone:false,
```

I don't know if that's all? For now i am just trying to get provide a notification if the user tries to select a date in the past. For that i am currently comparing the time now and the time provided by the "dayClick"-event of fullcalendar:

```
dayClick:
function(date, jsEvent, view)
        {
                var now = Date.now();
                console.log("date now:"+now);
                console.log("event-time by fullcalendar:"+Date.parse(date));
                console.log("difference between the dates:"+(now-Date.parse(date))/1000);
        }
```

For my local machine this seems to work pretty well.
Since the "now"-attribute of fullcalendar will be set by php, which is of course using the server time (correct?) the event date and the current date won't match anymore, because the time of the calendar is set by php (server-time) and the local timezone/local time will be set by javascript which is using the browser's time if i remember correct.

my actual question (respect to all you who continued reading until now ;) )
is, how do i solve this problem? can i detect the timezone offset with javascript and then pass it to fullcalendar with something like

```
now: "UTC+"+timezoneOffset
```

It seems i haven't understand the way fullcalendar handles timezones...:(

Comment: Hey Jan, dates & offsets in native JavaScript are horrible to work with. Luckily fullcalendar ships with [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/). This library can easily transform dates for you in local time or UTC time.